# How to select 2-dimensional ranges using variables and not "A1"-format?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I realize this must be a really basic question but I can't seem to get this right. This last month of trying to learn VBA always sees me stuck on problems relating to this. I have searched for the answer but still struggle. Some help would be appreciated!

So, what I want to do is to select and manipulate ranges based on their numeric order, like row1,col1 to row 15,col7. Instead of "A1:G15".

For instance, the following code should format the copy of a pivot table:

```
Sub layout()
Dim searchterm As String: searchterm = "Grand Total"

rad = RowIndexer(searchterm) 'finds location of last row 
kolumn = ColIndexer(searchterm) 'finds location of last column

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 1), Cells(rad, kolumn)).Style = "SAPBEXfilterItem"

End Sub
```

I have also tried converting the range to "A1"-style, to no avail:

```
Start = Cells(counter, 1).Address
Finish = Cells(counter, kolumn).Address
Range("Start:Stop").Style = "SAPBEXfilterItem"
```

This question is very generic though so don't focus too much on the actual application. Just tell me how to work with ranges when you usually have just indices :)

In both cases I'm only able to select the first column and not the entire range. I heard someone mention that VBA is not "matrix based" and a lot of code I look at seems to overuse loops. Is the problem actually that you can only manipulate one one-dimensional array at a time? That would be really annoying...

Comment: Your first code is perfectly fine. Have you tried debugging the values of `rad` and `kolumn`? Are your functions returning the correct values?

Comment: Well it works now after some modifications and it's possible that it was "kolumn" that errored. Regardless, I can swear I've had this problem (referenceing ranges with numbers) many times and it hasn't worked even when copy-pasting from others' solutions. I guess there must be some small, new thing I get wrong every time making it all fail.
Thanks for the help, at least I know I'm not doing it entirely wrong now!

Comment: I Don't know if you know about the "Immediate" Windows and the "Locals" one. They are very useful to debug such situations (available in "View").

Comment: Well I've known about them but haven't really figured out how to use them before (at least not the immediate window which I thought would type out info by itself when stepping through the function) but got around to it now and yeah, it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed select ranges by using Range and using Cells(row, column). The correct usage is as follows, to select A1:G15

```
Dim wS as Worksheet
Set wS = ActiveSheet

Range(wS.cells(1,1), wS.cells(15,7)).select
```

Note that I did specify which sheet I am using INSIDE the Range method and applied to the cells object. That's the proper way to do it.

Comment: Thanks!

It seems to be the case that aside from specifying an exact worksheet, sometimes you can write ".cells", sometimes just "cells". Is the ".cells" version when you reference something you have previously specified, like after a "with"-command?

Would upvote if I could :)

Comment: Well... everything depends on context :) If you use a module, the code is generally not tied to any worksheet, so you have to specify which worksheet to use by using `wS.Range`, `ws.Cells` and so on. If you write your code directly tied to a worksheet, you can omit that because excel defaults to the current worksheet (if you need to reference other worksheets, you still need to write them of course). `With` is just a construct to avoid having to write `wS.this`, `wS.that`, `ws.SomethingElse` all over the time, it just saves characters.

Comment: Sina covered it well. You can only use ".Something" in a "With ... End With" statement.
And even if VBA allows a lot of omissions (such as using "Cells" without specifying which worksheet), I strongly encourage you to properly point to the right object at all times, and declare your variables too (and their type, "Dim i" is useless, use "Dim i as Integer"). And indent and comment your code, it's worth saying it again.